# Can't upload files to Azure Storage using SSIS

Tags: azure, ssis, task

I want to upload image files from one of my local drives to my Azure storage container.  I'm using the **Azure Upload Task** in **SSIS**.

[image]
[image]

It is connected to the azure storage container just fine, and I'm targeting a specific container and place the images into a directory.  However, when I execute the task, it gives me the following error:

[image]
[image]

Error: 'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Unable to create Azure Blob container.

Error: Upload task has stopped with exception: Unable to create Azure Blob container.

Can anyone give me some help with this kind of problem?  Thank you.

Comment: Please copy paste the error text so it is searchable. Having said that the error says it's trying to create a container. Are you sure the path is correct? Depending on what you are doing this might be easier using AzCopy.EXE

Comment: Good pointing out.  I added the errors in order for them to be searchable.  Plus, the connection to the container tests successfully.  Also, I will try AzCopy.exe as a possible workaround.

Comment: I used the azcopy after following the tutorial on YouTube.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZLPQRJZEo_E

Comment: I just need to give my account the role of 'Storage Blob Data Contributor', and the I used AzCopy in my command prompt to upload the files from my local machine to the Azure cloud.  However, when I tried using the Azure Upload Task again, it didn't work.  It still gave me the same problems.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
If the error message contains anything like this:
*The TLS version of the connection is not permitted on this storage account*

the solution is to downgrade the minimum TLS version on Azure Storage in the cloud or do something with the TLS version on your on premises machine. You can find this setting on Azure Storage Configuration.
Default TLS on Azure is Version 1.2

If you downgrade (not recommended) there is a degree of security risk you are taking.

[Microsoft TLS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/transport-layer-security-configure-minimum-version?tabs=portal)

After these changes I can upload files using Access Key method or SAS (shared access signature).